# how to rename multiple files from array of number with python

Tags: python

I have 3 excel files name "files1, files2, files3". And i want to try to rename the files to the list of that array. But my code not working. Can anyone give me idea?

```
import glob

listOfNumber = [4, 5, 6]

files = "D:/Workspace/files*.xlsx"

for filename in glob.glob(files):
    for folder in listOfNumber:
        os.rename(filename, filename[:-6] + str(folder) + '.xlsx')
```

Comment: And what is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looping on `listOfNumber` **for each file**, trying to rename it many times.  You should instead loop **in parallel** over files and numbers:

```
for filename, newnum in zip(glob.glob(files), listOfNumber):
    os.rename(filename, filename[:-6] + str(newnum) + '.xlsx')
```

This way you'll be renaming exactly once per file, which is what you need.

Of course this assumes there previously exist no files already named like the target names you're using (else `os.rename` will fail, on Windows; it would succeed and remove the pre-existing file in Unix variants).  If the number of files found by `glob.glob` is different from `len(listOfNumber)` then `zip` will only proceed to the shortest of those two lengths.

But from how you describe your task, neither of these should probably be a problem for you (if that's not the case, edit your Q to clarify what problems are getting in your way, in detail!).

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the list of numbers and the files combined, split the path, then rejoin in the rename - note we're using `os.path` methods here to be filesystem agnostic, eg:

```
import glob
import os

listOfNumber = [4, 5, 6]

files = "D:/Workspace/files*.xlsx"

for filename, new_number in zip(glob.glob(files), listOfNumber):
    path = os.path.dirname(filename)
    os.rename(filename, os.path.join((path, 'files{}.xlsx'.format(new_number))))
```